# How to classify unseen data as anomaly

Tags: classification, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, anomaly-detection

I trained a CNN model with 6 different classes (labels are 0-5) and I am getting more than 90% accuracy out of it. It can correctly classify the classed. I am actually trying to detect anomaly with it. So what I want is, if any data comes which my model has never seen before or never been trained on similar data then it will be classified as anomaly while the other data point will be classified normally (from 0-5) same as before. I do not have any abnormal data to train my model, I just have the normal data. So the rule would be, if any incoming data point does not belong to any of the six classes then it is anomaly.
How can I do it?

Comment: Is this image data, or another kind of data?

Comment: It is Image data.

Comment: Is the goal only to do anomaly detection, or to do joint classification (for known classes) and anomaly detection (for out-of-distribution inputs)?

Comment: Only anomaly detection will do. Classification for known classes are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In a typical CNN there is a layer where all the data is merged into a 1d-vector, just before the classifier that maps onto classes. This vector representation ("embedding") can be used to create an "out-of-distribution" detector. This can be done by applying a standard outlier detection method to those vectors, for example [Local Outlier Factor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#local-outlier-factor). Or even train a reconstructing autoencoder.